# How can I see data for users created by a custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have Signup and Sinin custom policy that allow users to signup or signin. It works well.

The policy uses the following claims:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_firstName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_lastName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organizationName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_contactPhoneNumber" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_selectRole" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_terms" />
```

When I goto B2C portal, find the user and look the user details, none of the extension_* claims (attributes or properties) appear there.

Then I use Microsoft Graph, issue this query:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%5Buser) Object ID]

I get minimal data for the user. None of the extension_* calim data appears there.

How can I see all the extension_* claim data with a give user created by custom policy?

Comment: Use the beta endpoint of Graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure portal doesn't display the extension properties for users.

For the Microsoft Graph query, you must add [the `$select` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#select-parameter) in order to include the extension properties, such as:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}?$select=extension_{b2cExtensionsAppClientId}_firstName,extension_{b2cExtensionsAppClientId}_lastName,...
```

where `{b2cExtensionsAppClientId}` is the application (client) identifier (without hyphens) for [the **b2c-extensions-app** application}(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/extensions-app) that is registered in your Azure AD B2C tenant such as:

```
extension_b2ba52d57b074a5e8fa2d8b35f5a1347_firstName
```

Comment: You can also use `/beta/users/id` if you are not sure about the property names as it seems to return all of them. This could change in the future though.

Comment: Thankn you Chris and @juunas for solving this mystery